# Query Multiple Databases SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, sqlconnection

I'm having a problem running a query across multiple databases on an Azure SQL Server. This is the function I have made to return a DataTable from the query once it has been executed. The function takes the database name as a string and inserts it into the conenction string, along with the query to be executed.

The function works fine when I run it once, returning the DataTable populated with returned rows as intended, but when I call the function using a 'foreach' statement (Iterating through a list of database names) I get a timeout error or a login failed error.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
  public static DataTable runQuery(String db, String query)
  {

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=" + db + ";User ID=user@server;Password=password"))
    {

        con.Open();

        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {

            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(dt);

                cmd.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();

            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return dt;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the CommandTimeout to 0 means "infinite".  Maybe try something like 600, which is 10 minutes. (or something that makes sense for your problem).  "infinite" is a mighty long time.....Just a suggestion.

Comment: @granadaCoder the timeout is now 100, It turns out the problem was with the SQL database and not actually my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0`

```
try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(dtt);

                cmd.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();

            }
```

Comment: @Btop can you mark it as answer as hope your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` inside the foreach block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried that but I'm still getting a timeout error

Comment: How much interval did you add? it's on `Milliseconds`

Comment: @vikas Thanks for your help! That worked, but it takes a really long time to query just 3 databases (20s+), they are quite large databases but I'm only querying two tables. Any suggestions to improve the speed?